# Can you express this easy theorem in fancy categorical terms?

Tags: category-theory, homology-cohomology

Here is a theorem (of homological algebra):

> Given $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ in an abelian category
>   $\mathcal{A}$.
>
> If for all $D \in \mathcal{A}$ we have that $Hom(D,A) \rightarrow
>  Hom(D,B) \rightarrow Hom(D,C)$ is an exact sequence, then $A
>  \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ is an exact sequence.

This is a nice enough theorem that it feels like this can be expressed by saying that some certain representable functor is exact, or faithful, or a generator.

I tried using that an additive functor is faithful iff it sends nonexact sequences to nonexact sequences, but still haven't come up with anything.

Comment: "$\mathsf{Hom}(D,-)$ *reflects* exact sequences of length 3"? ;-)

Comment: You mean for a fixed choice of $D$? That can't be it, right?
To say that for some fixed $D$, $Hom(D,-)$ reflects exacts sequences of length 3 would be the following statement:

"Given $D$ and $A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ in an abelian category $\mathcal{A}$, if $Hom(D,A) \rightarrow
 Hom(D,B) \rightarrow Hom(D,C)$ is an exact sequence, then $A
 \rightarrow B \rightarrow C$ is an exact sequence."

And that's surely not a true statement. Whereas the theorem I gave is really a true statement, because it asks for the premise to hold over all $D$.

Comment: "Representables jointly reflect exact sequences"? Something in that neighborhood?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna have to go with @Malice on this one.

- Recall that a functor $F$ is “representable” 
  precisely when $F ≅ \mathsf{Hom}(D,-)$ for some object $D$.
- [Recall](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/103065/what-is-the-correct-definition-of-creation-of-limits) that a functor $F$ “reflects a property $P$”
  precisely when $P(X) \;⇐\; P(F\, X)$ for all $X$.

  ( This’ the converse of property preservation. )
- Recall that a *family* of functors consists of a functor $Fᵢ$
  for each $i$ in some index set $I$.
- Recall that a family $Fᵢ$ “*jointly* reflects property $P$”
  precisely when $P(X) \;⇐\; (∀ i.\; P(Fᵢ \, x))$ for all $X$.

Now your phrase can be stated compactly,

> “Representables jointly reflect exact ternary sequences”

Neato!

Comment: That's nice, I accept it.
Have you seen "jointly reflects" defined anywhere in the literature before?

Comment: I'm just extrapolating, but consider comparing with legitimate phrases such as "jointly monic" in which each member of the family must satisfy the monic premise in order for the monic conclusion to hold..

Comment: I actually googled this because I was sure I had just made it up on the spot, but "jointly reflects" has been used is basically this sense in the literature before. It looks like our sense of reasonable terminology is vindicated.

Comment: sweet! way to go MV!